# How to build an app with set reminder and get notification function in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an app I am working on and I would like to have a reminder in the app where users can set a specific time to be reminded of their daily task and when the time comes, the user should get a notification with a ringtone from their phone.

I have been trying to search everywhere but could not find a recent and detailed example.

Please I would appreciate if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try `flutter_local_notifications` plugin and look into the scheduled notification function